# Create branch from develop android studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, intellij-idea, bitbucket

How to create local branch in Android Studio/Intellij idea from remote - Develop, and then merge to develop? Then I creating local branch, see in first image link. It's creating from master and can be merged remote develop or master branches.

Android studio local branch creating from master

[image]

Commits tree, Bitbucket

[image]

Comment: Do you want to create a branch from develop? Type in command line `git checkout develop` , `git checkout -b your_branch`

Comment: Yes. I want create only from develop, because it got frequentsy updates. How checkout new branch from develop, without terminal?

Comment: "Without terminal"...what OS are you using?

Comment: Windows operating system

Comment: You have a terminal in Android Studio where you can run git commands, try it

Comment: @JuanCruzSoler how to do similar with GUI?

Answer (score 1):

> To check out a new local branch from a remote branch
>
> Invoke the Branches menu as described in Accessing Git Branches Popup Menu.
> Select a branch in the pop-up list that shows all available local and remote branches, and choose Checkout as new local branch from the submenu.
> Specify the name of the new branch in the Checkout new branch from  dialog that opens.
> The branch with the specified name will be checked out and put under version control.

Taken from [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/creating-a-new-branch.html).